# PyQGIS Rastermarker Maximum Size/Scale

Tags: pyqgis, markers

I am trying to set a "Maximum" scale or size limit for a RasterMarker inside PyQGIS. - Qgis 3.22

```
    self.marker = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:4326", "marker", "memory")
    self.marker.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("path", QVariant.String)])
    self.marker.updateFields()
    sym = self.marker.renderer().symbol()  
    rms = QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer()
    prop = QgsProperty()
    prop = prop.fromField("path") # This holds an awesome png path
    rms.setDataDefinedProperty(2, prop)
    sym.appendSymbolLayer(rms)
    sym.deleteSymbolLayer(0)
    rms.setSize(4)
```

i've been looking through documentaries and other questions, but i can't find something related to this.

however i did try to set a "SetMaximumScale" for the layer, but this did not really work.

```
self.marker.setMaximumScale(1.0)
self.marker.setMinimumScale(0.5)
self.marker.setScaleBasedVisibility(True)
```

How does one set a "Maximum" size so that when one zooms out. the marker basically remains the same on the map ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for `ScaleBasedVisibility` to work,
I had to look at it like this:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~< MinimumScale level 100000.0


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~< MaximumScale level 10.0
________________< Bottom Scale level 0 ?
```

So the code looks like this.

```
self.marker = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:4326", "marker", "memory")
self.marker.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("path", QVariant.String)])
self.marker.updateFields()
sym = self.marker.renderer().symbol()  
rms = QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer()
prop = QgsProperty()
prop = prop.fromField("path") # This holds an awesome png path
rms.setDataDefinedProperty(2, prop)
sym.appendSymbolLayer(rms)
sym.deleteSymbolLayer(0)
rms.setSize(4)
self.marker.setMinimumScale(10000.0)
self.marker.setMaximumScale(10.0)
self.marker.setScaleBasedVisibility(True)
```

Hope it helps someone else with the same issue.